# Django - search form

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Локация", default=u'')
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Ключевые слова")
```

forms.py

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    location = forms.CharField()
    keywords = forms.CharField() # e.g. 'spam,eggs,hum'
```

views.py

```
class AdvancedSearchView(FormView):
    form_class = AdvancedSearchForm
    template_name = "advanced_search.html"
    success_url = '/search_location/result/'

# url of this view is 'search_result'
class SearchResultView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "search_result.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        location = self.request.GET['location']
        location = location.upper()
        keywords = self.request.GET['keywords']
        # how should I use keywords (string of words split by commas)
        # in order to get locations_searched by name and keywords simultaneously
        locations_searched = Location.objects.filter(name=location)
        context['locations_searched'] = locations_searched
        return context
```

advanced_search.html

```
<form action="{% url 'search_result' %}" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form|crispy }}
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Find</button>
</form>
```

search_result.html

```
{% for location in locations_searched %}
       {{ location }}<br>
       {{ location.user }}<br>
       {{ location.keywords }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Please, explain (or advise where I can look at) how I can do matching keywords in model and keywords put to form in order to get Location objects by name and keywords.

For example, some object may keep as keywords - 'spam, eggs'

and in form I can enter only 'spam' or 'some,spam'

I'd like to get this object in this case

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

Then in get_context_data:

```
Location.objects.filter(Q(name=location) | Q(keywords=keywords))
```

You can also build your **QuerySet** in more statements by appending more **filter** methods to build complex variants.

Comment: Thanks! I've got direction.. but I still have question.. in expression Q(keywords=keywords) we have searching of such kind - e.g. if some user put string "spam, eggs" in the field KEYWORDS when creates object, then while searching I put in form "spam, stuff" - in this case searching is like "spam,eggs" = "spam, stuff".. but I need matching every word in model towards every word in search form.. and I want to get object even if I have concurring only some one word

Comment: For the record: IMO it's better to refactor the keywords to a many-to-one relation. Anyway; after you split the input on comma in a list 'splitted_keywords', you can do a text based search by looping through the list and adding this to your queryset: Q(keywords__contains=first_splitted_keywords[loopindex]))